# Load javascript

Tags: javascript, optimization

Our home page is 800kb, which is big I know.. 
We use social engine, which has a widget system which I assume uses Javascript
Currently the page is blank for several seconds.. nothing shows til the whole page has loaded.
My Q is: can we make the main widget load first..& show that while the rest of the page (& other Javascript) is loading?

Comment: Have you tried moving JS includes etc.. to the footer?

Comment: Don't forget this also depends on the browser. And 800kb for a homepage is huge. I would refuse loading that site.

Comment: I agree with @pistache that almost a megabyte for a home page is **way** too much. It can be several seconds on your connection but for some of your visitors that use mobile internet it can be several minutes and they are likely to think that your server just doesn't work and go to your competition - and later curse you when they see their phone bill.

Comment: 800k is huge? Really? From skashdot Dec '11:
"For most popular destinations, the average size of a single web page is now 965 kilobytes, up more than 30% from last year's average of 702KB.."

Comment: @JayJulianPayne Yes, 800kB **is** huge. Really. And yes, the average size of a single web page is huge. Websites with such a big overhead are a **terrible experience** for mobile users, especially if they pay for every kilobyte that is being transfered. 800kB is like 3 minutes with 40 kbps connection - no one will wait that long and it means **lost customers**. Remember that even a small increase in page loads means less sales. See: http://blog.kissmetrics.com/loading-time/

Answer (score 2):

Put the other JavaScript at the end of the `body` tag - just before `</body>`. If it is (as I assume it is in your case) in the `head` tag then loading, parsing and executing the script is most probably blocking the HTML that is below from being rendered.

If that doesn't help then see [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) and use the [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) plugin for Firefox.

Comment: Bandaid for a gunshot, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

There is some best practices to load your page faster (like [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)). At first, you should put your JavaScript load tag at the end of your body.